# "Invalid application name : Myapp" in sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am new in Sencha. i have created one project. i have generate workspace using cmd `sencha generate workspace C:\Path\project`. now i am trying to run cmd for generate app but showing ERROR "Invalid application name : Myapp"

CMD 1 :

```
cd /path/to/SDK 
sencha generate app Myapp C:/Path/Project
```

CMD 2:

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/sdk generate app Myapp C:/Path/Project
```

CMD 1 :

```
cd /path/to/SDK 
sencha generate app Myapp C:/Path/Project
```

CMD 2:

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/sdk generate app Myapp C:/Path/Project
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate a Workspace,Run this command on framework folder

```
sencha generate workspace /path/to/createworkspace
```

In your case:

```
sencha generate workspace C:\Path\project
```

For creating app inside workspace

```
sencha -sdk ../path/of/sdk generate app Myapp ./your appname
```

In your case:

```
sencha -sdk C:\Path\project\ext generate app Myapp sample-app
```

[Refer this Document for generating workspace](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.7.0/guides/workspaces.html#workspaces_-_generating_a_workspace)